# How to enable verbose logging for Webpack 5?

Tags: javascript, webpack, build

I could not find this information from the webpack logs, and some older answers suggests `--verbose` flag that did not work. Webpack 5 has [`--stats verbose`](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#flags) but the documentation does not tell much about it's behaviour so not sure if that gives out the full verbose output or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [logging level](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#level) in your webpack config.

```
module.exports = {
   //...
   infrastructureLogging: {
      level: 'verbose',
   }
}
```

if you want to include stats, you can include
`stats: 'verbose'`. [stats preset docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/#stats-presets)